# Difference in SSE/AVX vector types

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, avx

What is the difference between `_m256i` and `_m256d` and `_m256`? and
What is the difference between `_m128i` and `_m128d` and `_m128`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation states](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/cpp/lin/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_details.htm):

> The `__m256` data type is used to represent the contents of the extended SSE register - the YMM register, used by the Intel® AVX intrinsics. The `__m256` data type can hold eight 32-bit floating-point values.
>
> The `__m256d` data type can hold four 64-bit double precision floating-point values.
>
> The `__m256i` data type can hold thirty-two 8-bit, sixteen 16-bit, eight 32-bit, or four 64-bit integer values.

Answer (score 5):

Rule of thumb: an `i` suffix is used for all **integer** vector types, `d` is for **double precision** floating point vector types, and when there is no suffix it's for **single precision** floating point vector types.